Serilog logger using var logger doesn't output anything either on console or in file
In .NET, I have following code
var logger =  new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", assembly?.Name)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    theme: Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                    formatProvider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.File(
                    path: "Logs/log-.log",
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug,
                    formatProvider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                .WriteTo.Sink(new WebSocketSink(logChannel), LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
                .CreateLogger();

When I pass this logger as argument to other classes where ILogger is used of Microsoft,
the logging statements doesn't appear on console or in file.
But when I change it to
Log.logger = new LoggerConfiguration()..
logging statements starts appearing on console and in file as well.
Here is excerpt of class that I am using ILogger as argument
public class MyService(IDeviceIO devIO, ILogger<MyService> logger) : IMyService
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public void OpenDevice(string host)
    {
        
        logger.LogInformation("Device is being opened!");
        devIO.Open(host);
    }
...

Why can't I use var logger = .. ? Do I need to use Log.logger which static instance always ?

Show an example where you use that logger as argument.

@PMF : Updated my question with example you have asked. Let me know if you need more information.

I don't know the answer, but the question is much better now.

any chance you are using dependency injection that is not configured properly?

I am using DI. Can you @IvanPetrov provide proper DI example to resolve this ?

@BND try to debug the value of the logger inside the method as a first step

I see following values in logger inside the method
logger = Name = "App.Service.MyService", Enabled = false
| -- _provider  {Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider}
| -- _logger = null
@IvanPetrov Does it mean the DI has some issue ?

yes, focus on the _logger = null, why is that not throwing a NullReferenceException though, I am not sure

How do you configure the logging during startup? If this is an ASP.NET project, you should probably look at this answer here

Thanks @P. Magnusson for your help here with swift response !

Thanks @IvanPetrov for you guidance !

I found out the problem.
Added only three lines as follows and solved my problem
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Assembly", assembly?.Name)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Console(
                    theme: Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme.Code,
                    formatProvider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.File(
                    path: "Logs/log-.log",
                    outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                    restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Debug,
                    formatProvider: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                .WriteTo.Sink(new WebSocketSink(logChannel), LogEventLevel.Debug)
                .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
                .CreateLogger();
builder.Host.UseSerilog(logger);
builder.Services.AddLogging();


Thanks for help !
It was DI issue in short !
